# MVC3 input button that doesn't call controller action and just executes jquery event?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

On MVC3 Create view, How do I ensure that an input tag of type "submit" doesn't call Create action in MVC3 controller and only calls a jquery function?

```
function start()
{
   alert("hi");
}

<input type="submit" value="Start" onclick="start();"/>
```

Whenever I click on the Start button, it shows the "hi" alert box and then it calls a Create controller action again?  How do I ensure that it doesn't post back to the Create controller action?

thanks.

Comment: Are you binding to the submit event of the form? Or binding the click event of the submit buttons? Remember to either `preventDefault()` or `return false;` if you don't want it to proceed.

Comment: thanks return false did the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do something like

```
function start(e)
{
   alert("hi");
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

or if you only want to cancel the action specifically for that button, but not everywhere:

`<input type="submit" value="Start" onclick="start(); return false;"/>`

*note: I only tested the second, but I'm fairly sure the first should work too*

Comment: Where is that `preventDefault()` function defined?

Answer (score 1):

You could just change the `type` of the `input` from `submit` to `button`:

```
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="start();"/>
```

This would make it a standalone button that's not attached to an enclosing `form`.  That way you can bind your JavaScript code to it just fine and it makes no difference to the users, it just doesn't indicate to the browser that it should *also* submit a form.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need a call to `preventDefault()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#submitButton').click(function(e) {
            alert('hi');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
function start()
{
   preventDefault();
   alert("hi");
}

<input type="submit" value="Start" onclick="start();"/>
```